# pipes and error handling

Tags: error-handling, exception, pipe, elixir

Say you have the following function:

```
def get_city_temp(city_id) do
   'blahblahcityforcastfortoday.com/request/#{city_id}'
   |> HTTPoison.get
   |> parse_body
   |> get_forecast
   |> get_temp
end
```

Now say the `GET` fails, so that the response is:

```
{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 400, ...}}
```

but `get_forecast` is expecting a well formed body, and therefore will error complaining about the structure passed to it, or a missing key, etc. What's the best way to handle errors presented like this? In other languages I just wrap all the function calls in `try` `catch`s  and return a tuple with the success report. In this situation, I'm not sure how to structure my code to best report the error 
to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what the `with/1` macro is meant for. Assuming `parse_body` and other functions also return `{:ok, _}` on success and `{:error, _}` in failure, you can do:

```
with {:ok, response} <- HTTPoison.get(...),
     {:ok, parsed} <- parse_body(response),
     {:ok, forecast} <- get_forecast(parsed),
     {:ok, temp} <- get_temp(forecast), do: {:ok, temp}
```

If any pattern match fails, this whole thing returns that value. For example, if `get_forecast` returned `{:error, :foo}` after all previous functions returned `{:ok, _}`, the `with` will return `{:error, :foo}`.

Comment: The only thing is, `=` should be replaced with `<-`, otherwise it will `rise` due to problem when matching. Other than that, this is the way to go!